Google Cloud Functions triggered by Cloud Scheduler via internal url giving "URL_UNREACHABLE-UNREACHABLE_5xx" when they used to work fine
I've been running two cloud functions that are triggered by cloud scheduler cron jobs. They've been working fine for months until yesterday. Here is the log:
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished", 
"debugInfo":"URL_UNREACHABLE-UNREACHABLE_5xx", 
"jobName":"gcp_project", 
"status":"INTERNAL", 
"targetType":"HTTP", 
"url":"function_url"}

Nothing about the job has changed. Did Google update something or does anyone know how to troubleshoot? I've verified the url to the function is the same - again, was working fine for months.
Tried disabling and re-enabling the cloud scheduler api and created a new cloud scheduler job but did not work.

Issue seems to have been fixed by these steps: 1. Disable/re-enable cloud scheduler api. 2. Re-deploy cloud function. 3. Pause and resume cloud scheduler job.

I did this even two times but I am getting the same error again. Are there any more solutions?

Renaming the function and redeploying didnt help too

Are you using Firebase? I had the same issue. There a difference how you enter the Log-Explorer because different seems filters to be applied.
In my case using "Logs ansehen" works. Through "Cloud Scheduler" I had issues.

